# Submeter form com checkboxes vazios e receber o valor deles no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou pegando um formulário com **AJAX** e **Jquery** e enviando para tratamento em um arquivo **PHP** com nome **getPDF**, nesse formulário existe vários checkboxes  com valores diferentes porém name e class iguais (**name='`check[]`'** e **class='`toggle-check`'**).
Eu sei como pegar os valores nos campos checkbox checked com **foreach**, porém existe alguma forma de eu pegar todos valores de todos checkbox do form independentes de estarem checked ou não ?

Codigo PHP (Onde somente os checkbox checked são tratados):

```
   <?php
    include_once "../Data/config.php";
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
       $result="SELECT * FROM indicador WHERE nome = '".$check."'";
       $resultado = mysqli_query($dbc,$result);
         while($row_indicador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
          echo'teste com sucesso ';
         }
     }
```

Código Javascript que envia os valores para o **PHP**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 //envio o formulário para tratamento no getPDF.php
        jQuery('#formVerIndicadores').submit(function(){
            var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getPDF.php",
                data: dados,
                success: function(data)
                {


                    $('#resultadoPesquisaIndicador').html(data);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Codigo Html que foi gerado pelo PHP :

```
      <form id='formVerIndicadores' method='post'>
      <tr>
       <td>Carne bovina de corte</td>
        <td>
         <div><input class="toggle-check 1" name="check[]" id="" value="Carne   bovina  de corte" type="checkbox"><span></span></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>Bovino (kg*Pa)</td>
        <td>
        <div><input class="toggle-check 2" name="check[]" id="" value="outro valor qualquer" type="checkbox"><span></span></div>
        </td>
       </tr>
  //Pode ter N checkboxes dependendo da seleção em outro arquivo php
 <input type='button' value='Enviar'/>
      </form>
```

Comment: é a mesma coisa, a questão é que se não estiver marcado ele vem como `false`

Comment: E como recupero isso no meu php ?

Comment: como são montados os checkboxes no formulário? Como é o código do formulário? Pode postar o código da página do formulário?

Comment: Adicionado, a única coisa que muda de um checkbox para outro é a outra class que vai aumentando de  1 em 1

Comment: Adicionando manualmente? Ou com um WHILE php?

Comment: While  que percorre banco de dados, vc quer que eu bote a parte que ele gera os checkboxes ?

Comment: Só a linha  do while tá bom, pode ser em comentario `while .....{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na pagina `Código Html que foi gerado pelo PHP:`

> Comentários no código

```
while ($rows = ........
    .........
    .........
    //concatenando todos os valores do checkboxes
    $all_checkbooxes .=$rows['nomeColuna'].","; 
}
//fim while
//input type hidden com todos os valores dos checkboxes
// no value uma função para retirar a ultima virgula
echo "<input type='hidden' name='todos' value='".substr($all_checkbooxes, 0, -1)."'>";
```

Código PHP (Onde todos os checkbox são tratados):

```
include_once "../Data/config.php";
foreach($_POST['check'] as $check) {
   $result="SELECT * FROM indicador WHERE nome = '".$check."'";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($dbc,$result);
     while($row_indicador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
      echo'teste com sucesso ';
     }
}

$checados = $_POST['check'];

$todos = $_POST['todos'];

$explode = explode(",",$todos);
//retorna os valores que não estão presentes no array dos checados
$naoChecados=array_diff($explode,$checados);

foreach($naoChecados as $noCheck) {
    //o código para usar com os checkboxes que não foram checados
}
```

Código Javascript que envia os valores para o PHP: **nada a alterar**

### OBS

```
Use um `<button type='submit'`

<button type='submit' value='Enviar'/>Enviar</button>
<div id="resultadoPesquisaIndicador"></div>
</form>
```

### Sobre o atributo type dos buttons

1. submit: O botão envia os dados do formulário para o servidor.
2. button: O botão não possui comportamento padrão. Ele pode ter scripts do lado do cliente associado com os eventos do elemento, no qual são acionados quando o evento ocorrer.

[`<button>` - Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Comment: Obrigado meu caro, na hora não tinha pensado de criar alguns checkboxes hidden mesmo